# Oracle find duplicate column values with different ids

Tags: oracle, duplicates

My requirement is :
There is a table with the following values

[image]

I want a query which can fetch data like this :

[image]

It will be really helpful if I get a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is a self-join, or a correlated subquery

```
select
    id,
    name,
    street,
    (
        select listagg(t1.id) within group(order by t1.id)
        from mytable t1
        where t1.id <> t.id and t1.name = t.name and t1.street = t.stree
    ) associated_ids
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this quick help  .. my issue is resolved....